# Png image button with background in Android Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-imagebutton

When I use ImageButton in an activity it appears with a background color like this:

[image: ImageButton]

What do I have to do to remove this dark color?

Answer (score 1):

Use `imageButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);`

Or, if you want to do it in XML:  `android:background="@android:color/transparent"`

Answer (score 0):

If your png file has transparent background and you want a transparent background, save your image files with PNG 32 format.